# Suppose that the $n$ Gersgorin discs of $A \in M_n$ are mutually disjoint. If $A$ is real, show that every eigenvalue of $A$ is real.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose that the $n$ Gersgorin discs of $A \in M_n$ are mutually disjoint. (a) If $A$ is real, show that every eigenvalue of $A$ is real. (b) If $A \in M_n$ has real main diagonal entries and its characteristic polynomial has only real coefficients, show that every eigenvalue of $A$ is real.

The fact I tried to use is that if the union of $k$ of the $n$ discs that comprise $G(A)$, the union of Gersgorin discs, forms a set $G_k(A)$ that is disjoint from the remaining $n-k$ discs, then $G_k(A)$ contains exactly $k$ eigenvalues of $A$. However, I don't think this  fact leads to the result I'm trying to show. I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Any solutions, hints, or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof of both statements is the same. If the characteristic polynomial has all real coefficients, then any complex root $\lambda$ is accompanied by its conjugate $\overline{\lambda}$. But if a disk is centered on the real axis, then it contains $\lambda$ if and only if it contains $\overline{\lambda}$. Derive a contradiction of the second part of Gerschgorin's theorem from this fact.

Comment: I've got a few questions. Where is the assumption that the discs are mutually disjoint used? Also, how does the fact that any disk containing $\lambda$ also contains $\bar \lambda$ lead to the conclusion that all eigenvalues are real?

Comment: @user135204 One of the consequences of the Gerschgorin theorem is that if all the Gerschgorin disks are mutually disjoint, then each contains exactly one eigenvalue. This can't be the case if $\lambda$ and $\overline{\lambda}$ are both in one of the disks, unless they are the same.